# Is it possible to create a facebook page with graph api?

Tags: facebook

Using the facebook graph API (or any other means) is there a way to POST a new [facebook page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page) programatically?

The "Publishing to Facebook" documentation of graph API suggest to me that you cannot.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. Facebook does not support the creation of Pages, Users, or Groups through any of their APIs. This is to prevent spam. The only way to create new pages is on facebook.com

Comment: Is it still true? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ ctrl+f for "creating" and it shows that `You can make a POST request to owned_pages edge from the following paths:
/{business_id}/owned_pages
`

Answer (score 5):

According to two different documentation pages, page creation via API is possible BUT app whitelisting is required. Curious if @DonRzeszut applied for said whitelisting.

1) Pages API - Getting Started

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/getting-started#create-page

> Use the /user/accounts edge to create a Facebook Page.
>
> Requirements
>
> You can only create a Page as a test user or if your app is whitelisted. (You can apply through your Facebook representative.)

2) Graph API - Pages

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/#Creating

> Creating
>
> To create a Page using the Pages API, your app must be whitelisted. Contact your Facebook representative to apply for this feature.
>
> You can make a POST request to client_pages edge from the following paths:
>
> /{business_id}/client_pages

Answer (score 1):

There is another way of creating a "Page". You can use Open Graph Protocol to create "likable" pages on your own website.

See this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph

Comment: You still can't create the page with the api. Someone must click the 'like' button for the page to be created. Also, those pages aren't accessable by anyone but the administrator anyway.

Comment: You must add a like button to the page of course, aside from the open graph tags. Even if no one clicks the like button, it is still a "likable" page. The page is not created by facebook, the administrator itself creates it on his website. Those pages can be accessed by anyone as long as it's on his website. My suggestion is an advanced form of like-sites that have open graph.

Answer (score 1):

2018 update: I believe this is currently possible in the Graph API.

I haven't tested it personally, but [Facebook's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/accounts/#Creating) explains that pages can be created via the `/me/accounts` edge:

> You can make a `POST` request to `accounts` edge from the following paths:
>   `/{user_id}/accounts`

Please let us know in the comments if this works as expected.

UPDATE: Seems to only work for test users at the moment unless you're one of the rare few that has special permissions from FB.

Comment: This works. I got here from a google search and wanted to clarify for future finders how this works.That endpoint has some required fields: name (string), category (query /fb_page_categories and use the `id` value), about (string), picture (string), cover_photo (object {url:`cover_image_url`})

Comment: Yep, this works, but this works only for test users. If you want to call this method for a real user, your app should be whitelisted by Facebook.

Comment: @DonRzeszut Did you find this to be true? (test users only)

Comment: @rinogo It took me a moment to remember what i was doing this for. I was doing this to satisfy Facebook's permission approval process. So i was only doing this for a test user to create a test page. The docs linked in this answer specifically say what Daniel points out. In my experience, when Facebook says contact your "Facebook representative", it's not something they want you to do since most of us don't have a Facebook representative.